# In nest.js while using passport module do we have to use PassportModule.register() inside each modules?

Tags: typescript, passport.js, nestjs

If we don't import them inside each modules using @AuthGuard decorator then it's showing the following warning in logs.

> In order to use "defaultStrategy", please, ensure to import
>   PassportModule in each place where AuthGuard() is being used.
>   Otherwise, passport won't work correctly

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secretOrPrivateKey: 'secretKey',
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: 3600,
      },
    }),
    UsersModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Is there any other way besides importing "PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' })" inside each modules.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that your other Modules are importing the `AuthModule` in order to have access to the `AuthService` you could just re-export the `PassportModule`:

```
const passportModule = PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' });

@Module({
  imports: [
    passportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secretOrPrivateKey: 'secretKey',
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: 3600,
      },
    }),
    UsersModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
  exports: [passportModule]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Comment: To be clear, from that point on, other modules would just be importing the `AuthModule` class, yes?

Comment: it might be better to import a module once and use it on all children modules

Answer (score 3):

#### Simple solution

The `PassportModule.register({ … })` stuff is only needed *if* you want to use the AuthGuard syntax with an implied default strategy: `@UseGuards(AuthGuard)`.

It is not needed when mentioning the strategy explicitly every time:

```
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
// [...]
```

#### Solution with a default strategy

To avoid the above syntax that mentions the strategy in every decorator call, you can define your own guard that does nothing but provide an alias for `AuthGuard` with your default strategy of choice:

```
// file jwt.guard.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') { }
```

Then to use it, you don't have to do any `PassportModule.register({ … })` stuff in your module anymore. Just write this in your files:

```
import { JwtAuthGuard } from '../path/to/module/auth/guards/jwt.guard';

@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
// [...]
```

**Caveat:** The above custom guard, as shown, does not allow you to specify several alternative strategies at once: `@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard(['jwt', 'anonymous']))`. None of your strategies would be applied this way. Instead, you would have to use: `@UseGuard(AuthGuard('jwt', 'anonymous'))`. Feel free to improve.